# Damage modifiers in Diablo 3 items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just realized items **very** similar to this-item-which-does-not-fit-my-wizard are up for sale on the AH for 10 to 20 million gold (and only 2 out there, filtering by 96 dex, 14 attack speed, and 9 minimum damage).

[image: Rare Ring; +9 Minimum Damage; +9 Maximum Damage; +96 Dexterity; +43 Vitality; Attack Speed Increased by 14%]

This got me *(desperately interested in selling it)* wondering about the difference between damage modifiers, since I saw a similar item, that instead of having "+9 min/+9 max" had "+16-31 damage"...

[image: Rare Ring; +16-31 Damage; +47 Strength; +49 Dexterity; +54 Vitality; +27 Lightning Resistance; Attack Speed Increased by 14%]

Is this the same only syntactically different? If so, why is this happening? If not, what is going on, why are some properties so similar and yet different?

Also the AH doesn't let me look for +min-max damage modifiers nor by Maximum Damage, and to search for Minimum Damage I have to use an option that's not very clearly indicative of this (Bonus Minimum Physical Damage)

Also, I don't understand the minimum-maximum values altogether, for instance in off-hand items (sources or mojos always seem to have damage), it looks like maximum damage doesn't do a thing.

I wouldn't normally care about this but now that I've been paying more attention to the auction house, in order to price correctly items I sell and to buy items at bargain prices or even fair prices, this is a very important thing to grasp, since you don't have the +- damage/vitality/protection calculator that's offered in-game.

Answer (score 2):

These attributes are simply rolled separately. In this usual case, they were both rolled on the same item.

+All Damage items (e.g. +1-2 damage) is an attribute

+Minimum Damage (e.g. +1 to minimum damage) is an attribute

+Maximum Damage (e.g. +2 to maximum damage) is an attribute.

These are all rolled separately. However, I don't believe the +All Damage and +Min/Max Damage can be rolled together.

Answer (score 0):

Your inability to search for 16-31 damage is exactly why they're cheaper.  In order to find a good amulet with a damage range, you have to search for other abilities that you like, and then scan the results.

For similar amusement, try shopping for a high damage wizard source or witch doctor mojo.  It's basically like weapon shopping, without the ability to sort by damage.

Comment: that's my point, but besides that, what's the difference between minimum damage, maximum damage, and both in one property?

Comment: 16-31 damage is a different property than +9 minimum damage, and only one is searchable.

http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?816871-List-of-all-Affixes-with-Stats